# How can meta values from another site in a multisite be used in a custom query?

Tags: multisite, post-meta, meta-query, order, pre-get-posts

Currently, I am using the `pre_get_posts` action to create a custom query, ordering the posts based on a meta value like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_order' );

function my_custom_order( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_my_meta_key' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
  endif;
}
```

which works as expected.

As a next step, I want to use the meta values from another site in the same multisite network, not the values from the current site.

I have tried to switch blogs

```
function my_custom_order( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :
    
    switch_to_blog( 1 );
    
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_my_meta_key' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );

    restore_current_blog();

  endif;
}
```

which does not work.

Is there any way to achieve this, given the posts exist on both sites?

I do not want to query the posts from blog ID 1, just the order of the posts.

I am aware that synchronizing the meta data between the blogs would be another option, however, I would like to keep the data separated in order to be able to restore the order later on.

Comment: when you say the meta values from another site, how are you connecting the posts on the current site, to the meta on the second/alternative site? Given that they'll have wildly different post IDs I'm not sure how you plan to do this, but you need to know how they connect/map before it's possible to even start answering the question. I will say that while it's unlikely this is possible, it's a strong indicator that you're doing something wrong and there's a much better way to do what you want this for. What's the context for needing this?

Comment: The context is a multisite with three WooCommerce stores. The products are created on the main store and synchronized to the other stores via the WooMultistore plugin (https://woomultistore.com/). While it is true that the product IDs are different on each store, we are sure the products exist on all stores with the same slugs. Then, we’re using the Reorder by Termin plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/reorder-by-term/) to sort the products. By default, this needs to be done for each store. The goal would be to sort the products in the main store and use this order in the other stores.

Comment: in that case because post meta is tied to a post ID you'd need to add additional queries to map the IDs back to a slug, then to a slug on your current site, then back to post IDs. What you want to do is impossible via the `pre_get_posts` filter, and if it is possible will require raw SQL and be _extremely_ slow and expensive. If you manage to do this do not be surprised if the query takes 10+ seconds in the best circumstances. Synchronising the meta will save a _huge_ amount of time and effort, doing it the way you're asking will be slow, ultra difficult, as well as fragile & easy to break

Comment: note that because you're using re-ordering by term that adds an additional layer of complexity on top

Comment: Thanks for your assessment, I thought this might be the case. I’ll switch routes and synchornise the meta data.